# Chat messages not ordering correctly

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am use Firestore and Flutter for chat app. It work ok but I see this issue. Sometimes messages not display in order. For example usually they are sorted so most recent at bottom. But I test on iOS and Android simulator and see sometimes messages not display in order. For example I send messages on iOS and everything is ok (in order). Then I send on different simulator (for example Android) and the messages show at top and then start descending (on top of messages sent on iOS).

Here my code:

```
            child: new FirestoreAnimatedList(
              query: reference
                  .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                  .snapshots(),
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (_, DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                  Animation<double> animation, int x) {
                return new Chat(
                    snapshot: snapshot, animation: animation);
              },
            ),
```

`'timestamp': DateTime.now(),`

I have try this but same issue:

```
'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()
```

I look for weeks for answer but no find. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely encountering this issue because the devices are reporting different times.

To solve this, use the server time instead of local time. This is done by setting your `timestamp` field to `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#.serverTimestamp).

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am try now

Comment: @FlutterFirebase Any luck?

Comment: @FlutterFirebase No problem! Make sure to mark your question as answered if it is :)

Comment: i am also encountered this sorting issue tried your answer but no luck, pls help